# Cannot find function getTime() in object

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to compare two dates in Google Docs using Apps script. My dates are formatted m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss. I keep getting an error saying "Cannot find function getTime in object 2/1/2013 9:42:46." Is there a problem with the way my dates are formatted? I've used this before successfully for dates that are formatted mm/dd/yyyy, and am not sure why adding the timestamp would make a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 for (var i = 0; i < kValues.length; i++) { // repeat loop
   if (kValues[i][0] == "") {var lastupdate = parseInt(new Date("1/1/1980 00:00:00").getTime()/day); } // if a date doesn't exist, throw it back in the past
   if (kValues[i][0] != ""){
   var lastupdate = parseInt(kValues[i][0].getTime()/day);} // if a date does exist, interpret it. Here's where I'm getting my error.
   var statusDateChange = parseInt(statusDate[i][0].getTime()/day); // interpret a date from Sheet 2
   var statusChange = changeStatus[i][0]; //find the new status
   var currentStatus = status[i][0]; //find the old status
   var currentOID = oid[i][0]; // set Order ID
   var changeOID = statusOID[i][0]; // set Order ID in Sheet 2 to compare   
   Logger.log(lastupdate + "<=" + statusDateChange);
   if (lastupdate <= statusDateChange && currentOID == changeOID && statusChange != currentStatus) {sheet.getRange(i + 2, 8, 1, 1).setValues(statusChange); // if the date in Sheet 1 is less than the date in Sheet 2 and the ID matches, change the status

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there really a dot at the end of the string or is ot a typo ?  `2/1/2013 9:42:46.`

This might be the issue, you can test it like this :

```
Logger.log(new Date("2/1/2013 9:42:46."))
Logger.log(new Date("2/1/2013 9:42:46"))
```

returns

```
Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969
Fri Feb 01 00:42:46 PST 2013
```

the first value being equivalent to `Logger.log(new Date(null))` and returns the JS ref date.

Comment: There is no dot at the end of the string in my Google Docs. The error message has a period at the end of its sentence. I'm still very confused. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, yet I have an error!

Comment: Could you check with the Logger what is the exact value you have in kValues[I][0]  ?

Comment: I think I solved it. I copy/pasted dates from another sheet and for some reason Google Apps doesn't read them as dates even though I formatted them as such. When I delete the value in each cell and rewrite the date manually, the script works. Not sure why copy/paste doesn't work.